# Not being able to detect '-' character in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to test whether a character is a special character or not.

It fails for '-' character when I write the following code:

```
import re

s = '-'
regex = re.compile('[!@#$%^&*()-+]')

if regex.search(s) == None:
    print("Not found")
else:
    print("Found")
```

**Output>>Not found**

However, if I change the position of the '-' character in the pattern as follows (line 3 of code), it works correctly

```
import re 

s = '-'
regex = re.compile('[!@#$%^&*()+-]')

if regex.search(s) == None:
    print("Not found")
else:
    print("Found")
```

**Output>>Found**

What is causing this difference and how can I make sure that the characters will be detected?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: look at the characters in the character class `[a-z]`. It's more than three characters long!

Comment: Try escaping characters like re.compile('[\-]')

Comment: Got it. It should be either the first or the last character in the range. Also works with an escape character: regex = re.compile('[!@#$%^&*()\-+]'). Thanks!

Comment: Hi,  please take a look at the two questions I've marked. This is a common issue that has been asked before. If they don't address your problem please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 5):

`-` is treated as a special character *if* it is not the last or the first character in a range and not escaped. So:

- `[-19]` or `[19-]` or `[1\-9]` is `-`, `1` or `9`, but
- `[1-9]` is anything between `1` and `9`, inclusive, but not `-` itself.

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#regular-expression-syntax): "Ranges of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and separating them by a `'-'`, for example `[a-z]` will match any lowercase ASCII letter, `[0-5][0-9]` will match all the two-digits numbers from `00` to `59`, and `[0-9A-Fa-f]` will match any hexadecimal digit. If `-` is escaped (e.g. `[a\-z]`) or if it’s placed as the first or last character (e.g. `[-a]` or `[a-]`), it will match a literal `'-'`."

Answer (score 0):

`'-'` in Regex means between. 
So the first expression says

```
regex = re.compile('[!@#$%^&*()-+]')
```

Match characters between ')' and '+'

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html